# GET request in LUA - ">>" after send request

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I send my Lua code by Arduino IDE.

My sketch in Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial ESPserial(2, 3); // RX | TX

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);     // communication with the host computer
    //while (!Serial)   { ; }

    // Start the software serial for communication with the ESP8266
    ESPserial.begin(9600);  

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Remember to to set Both NL & CR in the serial monitor.");
    Serial.println("Ready");
    Serial.println("");    
    delay(1000);
}

void loop() 
{
    // listen for communication from the ESP8266 and then write it to the serial monitor
    if ( ESPserial.available() ) {  Serial.write( ESPserial.read() );  }

    // listen for user input and send it to the ESP8266
    if ( Serial.available() ) {  ESPserial.write( Serial.read() );  }
}
```

I open serial port and send my code:

```
conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) print(payload) end)
conn:connect(8080, "192.168.0.100")
conn:send("GET /json.htm?type=command&param=udevice&idx=3&nvalue=0&svalue=69 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.0.100\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")
```

But my ESP return ">>" after last command.. [there is screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjgvr.png)
[image]

When I replace conn:send on this:

```
conn:send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.0.100\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")
```

All is correct, I take respond from server...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Perhaps serial buffer are too short ? [SoftwareSerial](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/7380750a693557f56911dd873c4c7dbde0070b00/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.h) use a read buffer of 64 bytes.

Comment: Theres some pretty serious line noise in your screenshot too. Maybe the shorter string happens to work just by luck?